# Log4Net appender prematurely stopping on IIS Express Stop Site

Tags: multithreading, iis, log4net

I have a custom appender that derives from `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` and implements `IAppenderAttachable` and sends logging events to a queue (actually to a `BlockingCollection`, which internally adds to a queue and then via a separate thread removes from that queue and sends log message over http.

This works fine until the application has to close.  When that happens, the app closes and all messages in queue are lost.  I added a Close to handle that and wait until the collection is completed, but the code never makes it that far, it always just abruptly ends.  How can I get it to continue running until queue is empty or say 10 seconds elapse (in example below).

Here's the Appender OnClose:

```
protected override void OnClose()
    {
        this.Flush(true);
        _handler.Close();
        this.RemoveAllAppenders();
    }
```

and here's the Close for the handler (class implementing BlockingCollection):

```
public void Close()
    {
        _blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
        if (!_blockingCollection.IsCompleted)
        {
            _manualResetEvent.WaitOne(10000);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Actually finished!");
    }
```

Comment: I notice you're not calling `base.OnClose();` in `OnClose`

Comment: @stuartd true, but I'm actually inheriting from BufferingAppenderSkeleton which is also not calling `base.OnClose();`.  It just calls `this.Flush(true);`